# Subscribe to specific keywords on Facebook Groups?

Tags: facebook-groups

Is it possible to receive alerts if specific keywords are being used on Facebook Groups?

Comment: Any reply to this. I have seen this but this is when you are admin. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KkyXvxLLly8